# How to get Google Sheets to reliably compare text cells that include "<" and ">"?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet, equality, countif

As you can see in this sample scenario, I am having trouble reliably comparing cells A and B. It seems to have something to do with the "<" and ">" signs.

In my actual use case, I let conditional formatting highlight repeated values in a column using a formula similar to the one in cell C1 `=countif($A2:$A,$A2)>1`. However, that formula becomes totally unreliable when cells contain the "<" and ">" signs. This is a problem because I want to compare text cells that often contain HTML.

What’s the matter and is there a workaround?

[image]

I also recreated the image above using a table:

| A | B | =if(countif($A2:$B2,$A2)>1,"Yes","No") |
| --- | --- | --- |
| whatever> | <whatever | No |
| <> | whatever | Yes |
| whatever | <> | No |
| <><> | <> | No |
| <>whatever | `<whatever>` | Yes |
| <>whatever | <>whatever | Yes |
| whatever<> | `<whatever>` | No |
| whatever<> | <>whatever | No |
| ><>< |  | No |
| ><>< | `<whatever>` | Yes |
| <><> |  | Yes |
| <><> | `<whatever>` | Yes |
| <>< | >< | Yes |
| <>< | <> | Yes |
| ><> | >< | Yes |
| ><> | <> | No |
| <> | ><> | Yes |
| < | > | No |
| > | < | No |
| <> | >< | Yes |
| >< | <> | Yes |
| << | >> | No |
| >> | << | No |
| << | <> | No |

Comment: Apparently, prefixing `=` sign fixes it.`=countif($A2:$A,"="&$A2)>1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to compare A1 to B1 formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A24=B1:B24, "Yes", "No"))
```

[image]